# WP Taxonomies relations best practises

Tags: wordpress, taxonomy-terms

I am on a custom plugin for my company's inventory, and am actually not sure how to organise the basic WP taxonomies part. Each '*Item*' will be unique, and **has** to be related to a '*Projet*' and **can** be related to an '*Order*'.

I imagined the two setups below, using ACF for time saving purposes.

- 1 CPT for the inventory item
- 1 custom hierachical taxonomies, '*Project*' (with '*Order*' as children of '*Project*')

**-- OR --**

- 1 CPT for the inventory item
- 1 custom non hieracical taxonomy, '*Project*'.
- 1 custom non hieracical taxonomy, '*Order*'.

The first options is bothering me as '*Project*' and '*Order*' are not the same thing, and would need to be differentiated later (list all the '*Order*'regardless the '*Project*'for example), but offers the possibility to access directly a '*Project*' and all of its '*Order*'.

The second options lets me a bit bling on how to link the two taxonomies together using the less term_metas as possible. I know I could add a custom field to my '*Order*' linking to a '*Project*', but this is not how WP intended the use, I think.

What would be the recommanded solution to go to, maintaing evlovability, WP best practise wise ?